# "Credere a" vs "credere in" when they mean "to have faith/confidence in sth/sb"

Tags: verbs, prepositions

In English, "to believe" can be used in two constructions:

- to believe (transitive):

  - to think that somebody is telling the true. Ex: I believe the witness.
  - to think that something is true. I believe the witness's testimony.
- to believe in (intransitive):

  - to have confidence in somebody (eg his/her capacity). Exs: You must believe in yourself. I do not believe in doctors.
  - to have confidence in something. Exs: I do not believe in progress. I do not believe in the cure of cancer.
  - to have faith in the existence of something. Ex: I believe in God

In Italian:

- to think that somebody is telling the true: credere a qualcuno. Ex: Credo al testimone.
- to think that something is true: credere (a) qualcosa. Credo alla/la testimonianza del testimone.
- to have confidence in somebody: credere a/in qualcuno. Exs: Devi credere in/a te stesso. Non credo nei/ai medici.
- to have confidence in something: credere a/in qualcosa. Exs: Credo nel/al progresso. Credo alla/nella cura del cancro.
- to have faith in the existence of something: credere a/in qualcosa. Ex: Credo in/a Dio.

(Reference: http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/credere/)

I assume that usually there is a preposition which is more usual in the last 3 cases (e.g., "credere in Dio"), i.e., when "credere" = "to believe in", and that this usual choice must be learned by heart?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the last three cases there is, in fact, an option which is preferable over the other:

- When you have confidence in somebody you should usually use "**credere in**"; in the last example "*Non credo nei medici*" and "*Non credo ai medici*" have slightly different connotations, the former meaning that you don't have confidence in the doctors' abilities, and the latter meaning that you don't believe what the doctors say.
- When you have confidence in something the preferred form is "**credere in**".
- And finally, when you have faith in the existence of something you should use, once again "**credere in**".

Generally speaking, you use "**credere a**" when you believe something someone says (even when you use it referring to a person, like in the example  "*credo al testimone*", it references what the person is saying, not the person itself), while you use "**credere in**" when you have confidence or faith in someone or something.

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! A related question: could I say both "credere nella esistenza di qualcosa" and "credere alla esistenza di qualcosa" (as "credere" may mean either "to believe sth is real" or "to have faith in sth") ?

Comment: @AlanEvangelista I'm not sure if there is any difference, but I can tell you that 99.9% of Italians use the two in the same way. I guess the only preference comes from which is more used where you grew up.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista and also, in Italian if the word after "alla" or "nella" or similar words begins with a vowel, the vowel of "alla" isn't written or pronounced, and in its place you use the apostrophe ('). So it's "all'esistenza" and "nell'esistenza", not "alla esistenza"